# Problem with fix number of workspaces

Tags: workspace

I had a setup with 4 fixed workspaces and it was working fine up until now but the setting is not correct anymore. It seems I have a dynamic workspace again with 1 workspace.

The following commands do not change anything.

`gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior dynamic-workspaces false`

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces 4`

Is there another way of fixing the number of workspace to 4?

Comment: The same issue. Gala ignores dconf settings. `gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior move-maximized-workspace false` - doesn't work as well. Pantheon terminal - ignores dconf settings as well. waiting for an update.

Comment: Argh. Unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

There was an update which removed these gsettings keys and because of that they do not work anymore. I like this feature so I don't need it but I have found out that there is an option to stop going fullscreen on another space and make spaces fixed again by execution of

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter dynamic-workspaces false
```

I have test it a few times and it works for me, but I have enable it again, because I like the dynamic spaces option when you go fullscreen. In order to restore it, you can do it by exection of

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter dynamic-workspaces true
```

Comment: It does not work for me. I guess we are still waiting for some fix of this.

Comment: @Plussoyeur it works for me. at feb 27,2020. (remember do not run with 'sudo' )